# У контента сайта появилось странное поведение

Tags: html, css

У меня проблема, я не знаю как её найти, чтобы решить. Есть шаблон сайте, в нём куча всякой анимации на блоках, и когда начинаешь скролить страницу, то появляется подобный эффект как будто страница пытается адаптироваться под текущий экран.

Когда я долистал до конца, и начал листать вверх, то такого эффекта уже нет.
В консоли тоже не могу найти причину.
Может есть способ как отследить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ничего не понятно, где вы на видео листаете страницу? какой эффект? что панель нижняя(плючик и стрелка вверх) в низ в верх прыгает? так там всяко анимация бесконечная, посмотрите в devtoolse

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui, да, я не листаю страницу, Подобный эффект происходит когда листаешь и вот я попав в такой момент когда она бесконечно контент масштабирует. И заснял этот момент

Comment: так сложно тогда сказать ибо ничего не видно, нечего щупать. Попробуйте вставить в консоль, когда это происходит такое выражение: setTimeout('debugger;', 3_000) и через 3и секунды все на стр застопортися, тогда можете посмотреть в devtools е  какие стили меняются и почему, мб клас добавляется или медиа какие прописаны или анимация

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui, другого файлообменника не нашел https://dropmefiles.com.ua/ua/AmyzU .Получается что контент реагирует на анимацию. Анимация создает горизонтальный скролл и контент адаптируется под него. Не подскажите как избежать этого?

Comment: overflow-x: hidden; надо добавить обертке, которая начинает скролится, а ссылка у меня не открывается

Comment: @EkaterinaRatatui Спасибо большое, вы очень мне помогли. Напишите пожалуйста ответ, я его отмечу.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

overflow-x: hidden; надо добавить обертке, которая начинает скролится